# How do I use VBA to create multiple directories and place files within them? Word 2013

Tags: vba, ms-word

Please bear with me, I'm rather new to macros within Microsoft Office programs. Here's some background info: I'm working in a corporate environment as part of an IT team, using Microsoft Word 2013, and I'm on Windows 7. I have full read/write access to the C:\ drive, which is where I'm working within. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

What I am trying to do is this: I want to create a script that first creates a file folder within a directory (that does not use \ in the filepath), with the folder title being the document number +1 (or DocNum + 1), generates three files (.htm with respective HTML files in their own auto-generated folder, .txt., and .rtf) within that directory (each file has the exact same name), then moves back to the parent folder and repeats this process. The files are an email signature created from mail merging into a directory, then the directory file has the below script to create the files so we can push them down and lock them down for each user remotely.

Here's where I'm getting stuck: Trying to create the subfolder with the name being the "DocNum + 1" scheme, then creating the files within it. I am getting an Error 75. I can create each subfolder manually, but of course want the script to work. Even after 2 hours of Google searches and playing around with the VBA script I have yet to figure this out.

I do NOT need anything fancy (as defined by all sorts of error-correcting and double-checking code lines), and would prefer as bare-bones as possible (just enough to make it work as desired). I do not and cannot not install any extensions. Here's what I have so far (the entire script). Those more experienced with VBA can probably see what I'm trying to do here:

```
Sub BreakOnPage()
   ' Used to set criteria for moving through the document by page.
   Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowsePage

   For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages")

  ' Select and copy the text to the clipboard
  ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Copy

  ' Open new document to paste the content of the clipboard into.
  Documents.Add
  Selection.Paste

  ' Removes the break that is copied at the end of the page, if any.
  Selection.TypeBackspace
  Selection.TypeBackspace
  ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Users\User\Desktop\mm_files"
  DocNum = DocNum + 1
  MkDir ("C:\Users\User\Desktop\mm_files" & DocNum)
  ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Users\User\Desktop\mm_files" & DocNum + 1
  ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="Signature" & ".rtf", FileFormat:=wdFormatRTF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
  ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="Signature" & ".txt", FileFormat:=wdFormatEncodedText, Encoding:=msoEncodingUSASCII, AddToRecentFiles:=False
  ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="Signature" & ".htm", FileFormat:=wdFormatHTML, AddToRecentFiles:=False
  ActiveDocument.Close

  ' Move the selection to the next page  in the document
  Application.Browser.Next
   Next i
   ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You add 1 to `DocNum` twice: once just before creating the folder, and then again when calling ChangeFileOpenDirectory.

It would be better to pass the full path to `SaveAs`, instead of setting a default location.

```
Dim DocNum As Long, fPath As String
'...

DocNum = DocNum + 1
fPath = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\mm_files" & DocNum
MkDir fPath

ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=fPath & "\Signature" & ".rtf", _
           FileFormat:=wdFormatRTF, AddToRecentFiles:=False

ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=fPath & "\Signature" & ".txt", _
           FileFormat:=wdFormatEncodedText, Encoding:=msoEncodingUSASCII, _
           AddToRecentFiles:=False

ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=fPath & "\Signature" & ".htm", _
           FileFormat:=wdFormatHTML, AddToRecentFiles:=False

ActiveDocument.Close

'...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately I'm still getting Error 75 which states "Path/File Access Error," and the folders aren't generating. The mid-section of my script is now a carbon copy of your example. (from `DocNum = DocNum + 1` to `ActiveDocument.Close`. Any ideas why this would be the case?

Comment: I also do now have `Dim DocNum As Long, fPath As String` at the top of the script file below `Sub BreakOnPage()`, with the same result.

Comment: Is there actually a user named "User" ?

Comment: No. The correct username is in the code I'm using. When I don't try to implement any portion of the VBscript that creates a subdirectory/folder (beyond what is auto-generated by creating a .htm file), file generation is successful is that parent directory of "mm_files" (including the auto-generated .htm folders)